# When can a function be decomposed into 3 functions whose Jacobians make up the SVD of the original function?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Say we have a smooth bijective function $f(z)$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ whose Jacobian matrix can be factored using a singular value decomposition $\frac{df(z)}{dz}=USV^T$.

Can we always find smooth bijective functions $u(.), s(.), \bar{v}(.)$ so that $f=u\circ s \circ \bar{v}$ and the Jacobian matrices of $u,s,\bar{v}$ are $U,S,V^T$ respectively?

My guess is that for any $f$ the answer is no, but I'm not sure how to go about showing this.

Comment: For 2x2 matrices and eigendecomposition instead of SVD the answer is yes, it is always possible. For 3x3 and so on - not always. This is known fact about riemann invariants from the course about hyperbolic PDE's